# Check box size change with CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile

How can I change check box sizes (globaly) without class and id? Is it possible to do this in a way different from:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    zoom: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: And why does this approach not work for you?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`input` fields can be styled as you wish. So instead of zoom, you could have

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  width: 30px; /*Desired width*/
  height: 30px; /*Desired height*/
}
```

EDIT:

You would have to add extra rules like this:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  width: 30px; /*Desired width*/
  height: 30px; /*Desired height*/
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p36tqqyq/1/

Comment: I think I use this on my Website... might be wrong gonna check

Comment: This work i just check

Comment: I stand corrected; I tested using `150%` in my own tests which moved the checkbox into a larger area but remaining the same size. Using `px` does indeed change the size of the checkbox itself. Earlier comment retracted.

Comment: It does work if you override other browser styles as well (like background). You might have issues with just the size being stated in some browsers.

Comment: This is true. You should reset the value first in your css before applying it, else other browsers will override this. I can confirm this works, however I prefer using scale values, because it scales with browser size. On mobile devices, 30px looks different than scale sizes. Next to that, the density per screen varies, making 30px on a low rez much bigger than scale sizes. So it depends on what you try to accomplish :)

Comment: @Charleshaa can you show working fiddle?

Comment: @C-linkNepal http://jsfiddle.net/p36tqqyq/

Comment: I cannot see increased size of checkbox

Comment: yes same , checkbox still appear same size.

Comment: Well you should just change the values in the CSS, and see it working... What browser are you on ?

Comment: I've checked in `FireFox` v.31 and change the `width` and `height value`, still same

Comment: I have Firefox 29.0.1 and it works... I'm on a mac BTW

Comment: Just tried on v31.0, works also for me, although the other styles like colors are ignored.

Comment: I duplicated the size rules in the first fiddle, maybe that's it, this is the one working for me : http://jsfiddle.net/p36tqqyq/1/

Comment: This is interesting but without the check how does a user know if the checkbox has been checked? Becomes a mystery meat form element without check.

Comment: @b_dubb you can use the pseudo-class `input[type="checkbox"]:checked` to style it as you wish.

Comment: just a note, that `outline: 0 none;` is evil

Answer (score 27):

You might want to do this.

```
input[type=checkbox] {

 -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
 -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
 -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
 -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: The solution has problem on chrome from mac. The checkbox is blury

Comment: You might want to do this, but you probably don't. It's super pixelated and not acceptable for most applications.

Comment: thanks. works fine

Comment: Now there is no need to use the browser specific options.

Comment: This makes it really pixelated though

Comment: The scale approach makes the checkbox icon blurry.

Answer (score 22):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5;" />
/* The value 1.5 i.e., the size of checkbox will be increased by 0.5% */
```

Comment: doesn't work for firefox